# Creating new folder in Share point from D365 FO through Rest API

Tags: sharepoint

I am using D365 Finance and operations - Whenever a new record is created in the form it needs to create one folder in share point - For that I have added the below code. I tried giving all the API URL, but its showing error as "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found". Below is my code. Error is throwing when we are trying to get the response.

```
        str                 apiUrl;
        System.Exception    ex;
        ISharePointProxy    proxy;
        String255 fNewFolder = _projTable.ProjId;
        String255 fServer = 'https://test.sharepoint.com/SharePointIntegrationD365FO';
        String255 fRootFolder = 'Documents';
        System.UriBuilder   builder     = new System.UriBuilder(fServer);
        str                 hostName    = builder.Host;
        str                 siteName    = fRootFolder;
        str externalId = xUserInfo::getCurrentUserExternalId();
        boolean validConnection = false;
        proxy   = SharePointHelper::CreateProxy(hostName, '/', externalId);
        if(proxy)
        {
            if(SharePointHelper::VerifyAuthentication(proxy))
            {
                validConnection = true;
                info(strfmt('@ApplicationFoundation:SPServerCommunicationSuccess', hostName));
            }
            else
            {
                info(strfmt('@ApplicationFoundation:SPServerUserNotAuthorized', hostName));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            info(strfmt('@ApplicationFoundation:SPSelectionDlg_ErrorNoProxy', hostName));
        }
        if(validConnection)
        {
            apiUrl = strFmt("%1/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('%2')/folders/add('%3')", fServer, fRootFolder, fNewFolder);
            //apiUrl = strFmt("%1/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('%2')/Folders/add('%3')",fServer, fRootFolder, fNewFolder);
            //apiUrl = strFmt("%1/_api/web/folders/add('%3')",fServer, fNewFolder);
            
            try
            {
                str token = proxy.AccessToken;
            
                System.Net.WebHeaderCollection  httpHeader  = new System.Net.WebHeaderCollection();
                httpHeader.Add("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + token);

                HttpWebRequest                  request     = System.Net.WebRequest::Create(apiUrl);
                request.set_Headers(httpHeader);
                request.set_ContentLength(0);
                request.set_Method("POST");
                request.set_ContentType("application/json;odata=verbose");

                System.Net.HttpWebResponse  response        = request.GetResponse();
                int                         statusCode      = response.get_StatusCode();

                info(strFmt("HTTP status code: %1", statusCode));
                
            }
            catch
            {
                //exception
                ex = CLRInterop::getLastException().GetBaseException();
                error(ex.get_Message());
            }
        }
```

Thanks.